# populate or aggregate 2 collection with sorting and pagination

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I just use mongoose recently and a bit confused how to sort and paginate it.

let say I make some project like twitter and I had 3 schema. first is user second is post and third is post_detail. user schema contains data that user had, post is more like fb status or twitter tweet that we can reply it, post_detail is like the replies of the post

user

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    full_name: {
        type: String
    },
    age: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

post

```
var postDetailSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    message: {
        type: String
    },
    created_by: {
        type: String
    }
    total_reply: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

post_detail

```
var postDetailSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    post_id: {
        type: String
    }
    message: {
        type: String
    },
    created_by: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

the relation is user._id = post.created_by, user._id = post_detail.created_by, post_detail.post_id = post._id

say user A make 1 post and 1000 other users comment on that posts, how can we sort the comment by the username of user? user can change the data(full_name, age in this case) so I cant put the data on the post_detail because the data can change dynamically or I just put it on the post_detail and if user change data I just change the post_detail too? but if I do that I need to change many rows because if the same users comment 100 posts then that data need to be changed too.

the problem is how to sort it, I think if I can sort it I can paginate it too. or in this case I should just use rdbms instead of nosql?

thanks anyway, really appreciate the help and guidance :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MongoDB.
If you want to do it in the way you describe, just don't go for Mongo.
You are designing the schema based on relations and not in documents.
Your design requires to do joins and this does not work well in mongo because there is not an easy/fast way of doing this.

First, I would not create a separate entity for the post details but embedded in the Post document the post details as a list.

Regarding your question:

> or I just put it on the post_detail and if user change data I just
>   change the post_detail too?

Yes, that is what you should do. If you want to be able to sort the documents by the userName you should denormalize it and include in the post_details.
If I had to design the schema, it would be something like this:

```
{
  "message": "blabl",
  "authorId" : "userId12",
  "total_reply" : 100,
  "replies" : [
    {
      "message" : "okk",
      "authorId" : "66234",
      "authorName" : "Alberto Rodriguez"
    },
    {
      "message" : "test",
      "authorId" : "1231",
      "authorName" : "Fina Lopez"
    }
    ]
}
```

With this schema and using the aggregation framework, you can sort the comments by username.
If you don't like this approach, I rather would go for an RDBMS as you mentioned.

Comment: thanks for your fast response sir. oh so we just can join that 3 document with relation into 1 document. but let say that user comment more than 1000 post over the year, do you think update the 1000 post for just change the _authorName_ is good? or is mongodb is fast and sufficient enough to do it?

Comment: Your welcome :).
I still would have 2 collections, one for the user and another for the posts with the comments even tho you have duplicated information. I think 1000 posts are ok, mongo can handle it. Also, I find that updating the authorName is not a common operation (I don't think the user will be changing his name every day) and not a critical operation either. Anyway, I am sure you won't take that long in updating 1000 records if you have the proper indexes. Maybe 1-2 seconds at most.

Comment: ah I see.. actually I never test it. but I think update 1000 data for changing full_name is irrelevant.. guess I need to change my mindset from rdbms. thanks sir I will accept this answer. thank you :))

Comment: I think changing the mindset is the first step :)
You can contact me if you need further help. Have a nice day!